# pika with celery, connection closed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using celery with RabbitMQ to run some tasks, sometimes I need to return a message from the workers back to the RabbitMQ so i'm using pika.

I'm currently using the BlockingConnection() in order to connect to the RabbitMQ but after a while I get an exception "Connection Lost".

I believe that it happens because celery is asynchronous and I'm using the BlockingConnection().

This is my code:

```
class RabbitConnection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=RABBITMQ_OUT_NAME, durable=True)
        self.channel.confirm_delivery()

    def add_alert(self, new_alert):
        message = new_alert.to_json()
        delivered = self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                               routing_key=RABBITMQ_OUT_NAME,
                                               body=message,
                                               properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                                   delivery_mode=2,
                                                   content_type='application/json',
                                               ))
```

Should I use a different connection? if so how should I use it?

Comment: Is this multi-threaded? Pika is limited to one connection per thread. You could try a thread-safe library like my own https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm

Comment: Sounds great, can you please give me a simple example based on my code how to implement your thread-safe library?

Comment: I posted some example code. Let me know if I missed something, as I didn't have time to test the code out.

Comment: Understand, it is around 3 years. But, connection close happened for me, as it is trying to use IPv6 address. And so, I tried 127.0.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this could be a threading issue. You can handle requests with Pika over multiple threads, but ideally you should have one connection per thread, or [use locking](https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py). Instead of adding additional complexity to your code I would recommend that you use a thread-safe library; such as [amqp-storm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm) or [rabbitpy](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy).

If you would implement this using my AMQP-Storm library, the code would look something like this.

```
import amqpstorm

class RabbitConnection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = amqpstorm.Connection('localhost', 'guest', 'guest')
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue.declare(queue=RABBITMQ_OUT_NAME, durable=True)
        self.channel.confirm_deliveries()

    def add_alert(self, new_alert):
        message = new_alert.to_json()
        delivered = self.channel.basic.publish(exchange='',
                                               routing_key=RABBITMQ_OUT_NAME,
                                               body=message,
                                               properties={
                                                   'delivery_mode': 2,
                                                   'content_type': 'application/json',
                                                })
```

Comment: This example will be thread-safe or should I do anything else?

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to sacrifice ~5ms of latency per request:

```
import pika

class PikaClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None

    def __enter__(self):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='myqueue')
        self.connection = connection
        self.channel = channel
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.connection.close()

    def messageSent(self, msgStr):
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='myqueue', body=msgStr)
```

and then when you want to send a message:

```
with PikaClient() as pClient: 
    pClient.messageSent("my message")
```

Depending on your application, 5ms of latency may be a price worth paying.  If your app becomes successful you'll probably want to rewrite anyway, and then you can use a language with better multithreading features such as Java.